# locationManager.requestLocationUpdates Hangs

Tags: android, gps

Given the following simple class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   TextView tv;

   protected void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location)
   {
      tv.setText("test");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     // Define a listener that responds to location updates
     LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


    tv=new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout lyo=new LinearLayout(this);
    Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setText("aaa");
    lyo.addView(btn);
    lyo.addView(tv);
    setContentView(lyo);

}
```

the `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);` hangs while debug, and overall while running the app I am getting:

```
Process: com.example.social.gps, PID: 964
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.social.gps/com.example.social.gps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.social.gps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        ....
```

Any idea why?

I have in my menifest:

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: which is your 28th line ?

Comment: The stacktrace tells you where the error is MainActivity.java class line 28.

Comment: line 28 is a comment  `// Define a listener that responds to location updates`

Comment: Well, for one thing your timeout for your `LocationListener` is set to zero - which means you'll get constant info about your location. Second, since you're running the `LocationListener` on the main UI thread, it will hang the whole app. So, you get the `NullPointerException` because there's not sufficient time for the UI to create your view, layout, or button.

Comment: but the hang is before the `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);`

Comment: If I were to do this, I would separate the `LocationListener` component into a separate class, then have a **Service** that starts the `LocationListener` class. Also, you would need to provide users with preferences so they can set the minimum time interval between location updates (See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) for more info). Having `LocationListener` running constantly will chew up battery juice real quick - your users will be pissed.

Comment: @ChuongPham - I first want this simple app to run. Later on I will add what you metion.

Comment: FYI: Comment lines are ignored by the Android compiler, so the `NullPointerException` you got cannot be on this comment line. Please check again, I'm definitely sure it's not the comment line.